# How to get current date (date only format) in java and save it in a Notes document

Tags: java, xpages

How can I define a date field that contains only the date, and how can I save it back to a Notes document?

I tried:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = new Date();
doc.replaceItemValue("employee_Created", dateFormat.format(date));
```

but then I save the value in text format and that is not want I want.

Comment: Try with "-" instead of "/" to separate date items.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use DateTime's [setAnyTime()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_SETANYTIME_METHOD_JAVA.html). It removes the time part:

```
DateTime dateTime = session.createDateTime(new Date());
dateTime.setAnyTime();
doc.replaceItemValue("employee_Created", dateTime);
```

The resulting item "employee_Created" is just a date without a time:

[image]